# What's the most efficient way to access specific, related member variables via a single function call?

Tags: optimization, arduino, embedded

I'm trying to utilize a single function call to access multiple data members of a class called "Data." In this particular instance, I'm accessing the data fed to the class from a physical gyroscope sensor. This is what I've got:

```
template <typename T>
T Data<T>::getGyro_euler(char c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
    case 'x': return m_eulerX;
    case 'y': return m_eulerY;
    case 'z': return m_eulerZ;
    default: return 0;
  }
}
```

The data type this function uses is always either a float or a double.

Performance is more important than clarity in this case, as this is running on an already-overburdened Arduino that needs to perform mission-critical tasks, but something just feels kind of dirty about manually passing a character to a function to get a certain variable out of it.

I've got a number of functions like this with quite a number of variables that need to be passed, so having a getter function for each variable would get quite hefty in the code.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Is there a better, more clear way to accomplish the same thing without sacrificing performance?

Comment: Three functions shouldn't impact performance at all. Compared with your code, it should even go up.

Comment: I suppose inlining the function might improve performance, at the cost of some space.

Comment: More context is needed to answer this properly; why do you need a switch for the three axes? Also, a good compiler will practically eliminate any trace of getters from the final code. Have you checked the resulting code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably named your class `Data` for a reason : it is (or at least should be) plain data. Don't make it a class, make it a structure, or better yet, a [POD type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType).

That way you can access any member you want just by typing its name after a dot : `data.eulerX`. As a bonus, you get no performance issue, more clarity and better readability.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your approach is too complicated for the problem you describe.
As others mentioned in the comment accessing fields would be sufficient. You could choose to group together fields that are meant to be used together to improve the readability of your code using for instance std::tuple.

Below an incomplete example (as I don't know how the data is collected).
The performance cost is not related to the number of line of code, but more to the complexity the code involve (for instance here there won't be a need for a switch occuring at runtime); for the trivial types (double) described in the question I don't think it will be an issue.

```
#include <tuple>

struct giroData
{
private: 
    double sensorX;
    double sensorY;
    double sensorZ;
// or
std::tuple<double, double, double> sensor;

public :
    double getSensorX() { return sensorX; }
    double getSensorY() { return sensorY; }
    double getSensorZ() { return sensorZ; }

    std::tuple<double, double, double> getSensor() { return sensor; }

};

int main()
{
    double x, y, z;
    giroData d;

    x = d.getSensorX();
    y = d.getSensorY();
    z = d.getSensorZ();

    // or
    std::tie(x, y, z) = d.getSensor();

}
```